# Generate Parentheses Recursion passing as list vs string

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was solving the Generate Parenthesis question in leetcode. If I use the below code (cur as a list to append):

Here f is counter for forward brackets and b is a counter for backward brackets.

```
def generateParenthesis(n: int) -> List[str]:

    def recursion(f, b, cur=[]):

        if len(cur)==(n*2):
            a ="".join(cur)
            output.append(a)
            return
        if f:
            cur.append("(")
            recursion(f-1,b, cur)
        if b:
            cur.append(")")
            recursion(f,b-1, cur)
    output = []
    f = n
    b = n
    recursion(f, b, cur)

    return output
```

When I run the above solution I get the output as for n =3:

> ["((()))"]

if instead of appending to a list, I use cur as a string and add "(" to it I get the right answer.

```
def generateParenthesis(n: int) -> List[str]:

    def recursion(f, b, cur=""):

        if b < f or b<0 or f<0:
            return

        if len(cur)==n*2:
            output.append(cur)
            return
        if f:
            recursion(f-1,b, cur+"(")
        if b:
            recursion(f,b-1, cur+")")


    output = []
    f = n
    b = n
    recursion(f, b)

    return output
```

This produces the current output which is:

> ["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]

I know strings are immutable so adding "(" to string is O(N). I was just trying to avoid that. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here and if/how can we use the first code in the right way. I think it has to do with using a separate list (variable named cur) in each recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't like the syntax for `-> List[str]:` and `recursion(f, b, cur)`, as List is not defined in the code and cur is not defined in the area as well.

Now let's look at your code in the first section.

```
def generateParenthesis(n: int) -> List[str]:

    def recursion(f, b, cur=[]):

        if len(cur)==(n*2):
            a ="".join(cur)
            output.append(a)
            return
        if f:
            cur.append("(")
            recursion(f-1,b, cur)
        if b:
            cur.append(")")
            recursion(f,b-1, cur)
    output = []
    f = n
    b = n
    recursion(f, b, cur)

    return output
```

The variable `cur` in passed into the recursions **by reference**. That means, all called recursions share the same `cur` variable. So in the execution, once `"((()))"` generated, the other recursions will still increase the length of `cur`, making `"((()))"` the only output. So if you . change the condition to `if len(cur) >= n*2`,  you will get the below ouput.

> ['((()))', '((())))', '((()))))', '((())))))']

To make your code working, a naive way is to create a new list every time you call the recursion. For example, `recursion(f-1, b, deepcopy(cur))`, where `deepcopy` is `from copy import deepcopy`. But I believe you would rather use the **immutable string** in this case.

On the other hand, you can also see the list as a **stack**. Every recursion call, you append a parenthesis, meaning you **push** a parenthesis in the stack.  Therefore, you should also **pop out** the pushed parenthesis after the recursion call. Although in this case, your previous checking condition should be used.

Since Python's `list` is something similar to C++'s `vector`, we can just maintain the index of our last element instead of actual popping out. The code after modification should be

```
def generateParenthesis(n):

    def recursion(f, b, cur=[None] * (2*n), idx= 0):

        if b < f or b<0 or f<0:
            return

        if idx >= (n*2):
            a ="".join(cur)
            output.append(a)
            return
        if f:
            cur[idx] = "("
            recursion(f-1,b, cur, idx + 1)
        if b:
            cur[idx] = ")"
            recursion(f,b-1, cur, idx + 1)

    output = []
    f = n
    b = n
    recursion(f, b)

    return output
```

And let's do `print(generateParenthesis(3))`, we get

> ['((()))', '(()())', '(())()', '()(())', '()()()']

Good.

PS: Python doesn't have a native `linkedlist` but has a native `deque` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), you may use this data structure when a more complicated push and pop is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (n: int) -> List[str] is taken from Leetcode directly, it denotes input as an integer and return as a list

Comment: Thanks for @cdlane's timing. Python's list is a dynamic array, so the implementation should change.

Answer (score 1):

> I know strings are immutable so adding "(" to string is O(N). I was
>   just trying to avoid that.

But the interesting part is your string solution is 25% *faster* than @Tony's mutable list-based solution!  At least with my timings of `generateParenthesis(13)`.

Below's my string-based solution -- it's about 15% *slower* than @Tony's but has *no side effects* and can be converted to a(n even slower) list-based solution without *dangerous defaults*.  I.e. you can move the inner recursive function to its own top level function and it will still work:

```
def parenthesis(n):

    def parenthesis_recursive(k, f, b, current=""):
        if not b >= f >= 0 <= b:
            return []

        if len(current) == k:
            return [current]

        return parenthesis_recursive(k, f - 1, b, current + "(") + parenthesis_recursive(k, f, b - 1, current + ")")

    return parenthesis_recursive(n * 2, n, n)

print(parenthesis(3))
```

Comment: Thanks for your timing. I have misused list as a linked list. Now I have changed the implementation. The reason is that 'list' is a vector, therefore the remove and add is costly. You can time again for the new implementation.